# Hiding individual businesses in the Google Maps Platform JSON

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-styling

I am currently working on an Android app where i'm implementing the Google Maps feature.

The app is focused around a certain festival in my home town. And as of right now, it just zooms into the main position of where the festival will be. I will be adding custom markers, to give the user more info about where stuff like toilets, bars, food, etc, will be. But that's not relevant for the question.
This is what it currently looks like when you open the map functionality of the app:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOYgn.jpg)

I am using the [styling functionality](https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/) that google provides, and i have found that i can remove businesses and roads from the map if i wanted to. But i have yet to find a way to remove individual businesses via the styling functionality.
More specifically, i want to remove the one business in the bottom left. So far i have yet to find a way to do exactly this, if it is even possible, as it has no relevance for the festival at all.

**So my question remains, is there any known way to actually remove individual businesses from the Google Maps functionality that i implemented?
Whether that is through the Styling functionality mentioned above, or some other way.**

Answer (score 0):

From your [link](https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/) with `Create map style -> MORE OPTIONS`

[image: Styling: more options]

and then `Business -> All -> hidden` selection

[image: Styling Business-All-hidden]

you'll got something like that:

[image: Styling hidden business]

for map style. Than, you should add created style to your app, like in [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/styling) tutorial.

Comment: While i know i can remove all businesses, i only want to remove a certain one. 

I am aware you can remove all businesses or roads or whatever, via the styling functionality. But i'm looking to remove individual ones, not all at once.

Comment: @RubenMoen You can't delete only one object of style group. So remove it all, and add needed manually as markers in your app. Or use [GroundOverlay](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/GroundOverlay) for overlap places with business that you want to hide. Overlay image you can get from stylized map with all business hided.